# keyboard popup to scroll up full layout in android

Tags: android

i want to scrollup full layout when edit text focus to popup keyboard.i didn't find any solution.i want to like facebook app. facebook android app login page when edittext focused keyboard popup full screen scroll up to top like shown below figure:

before keyboard popup like figure below:

[image]

after keyboard popup scroll screen to up

[image]

can anyone help me.

Comment: Are u solve this problem.If you were solved this problem just post your answer which is use full for others...Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code in `onCreate()` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Try this in the android manifest file corresponding to the activity.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: i already tried adjustpan(only adjust gaps between edittext and keyboard) but i want to scroll up full screen can u give me solution?

Comment: That's actually not what he would want. In this instance, he would want to use adjustResize.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in manifest file, inside your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```