# how to center android Textview element at bottom of the screen

Tags: android, html, css

I have the android xml layout using DroidDraw :
link : [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L3QJVwI9Znmeu1yANJXhDcZGFR70587d4oznu0hrZCw/edit?usp=sharing0](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L3QJVwI9Znmeu1yANJXhDcZGFR70587d4oznu0hrZCw&authuser=0)

[image]

I need to bottom align the last Textview (Yellow one as indicated in the print screen).

i.e.

I need this :

[image]

Comment: we need all the parameters of your `TextView` to give you a 100% correct answer. Otherwise its guessing

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align views at the bottom of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post did the trick.

[stackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050228/creating-login-layout-like-in-facebook-app-for-android)

I needed to implement layout_weight on my layouts. Basically defining weights for header, content and footer

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
android:alignParentBottom="true"
```

If I see correctly that the parent ViewGroup of your TextView is a RelativeLayout

Comment: Ive paste the code for the xml   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L3QJVwI9Znmeu1yANJXhDcZGFR70587d4oznu0hrZCw&authuser=0

Comment: try now please : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L3QJVwI9Znmeu1yANJXhDcZGFR70587d4oznu0hrZCw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Repalce android:layout_gravity="bottom | left" with android:gravity="bottom" in your LinearLayout ( id/widget73 )

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent relative layout property to:

```
android:layout_gravity = "bottom | left"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Relative layout use:

```
    android:alignParentBottom="true"
```

and In Linear layout use:

```
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
```